# How do I make my particular WordPress public?

Tags: domain, domain-mapping, xampp

I have XAMPP running Apache and MySQL and I have installed WordPress already.

I bought a domain and have made sure that the nameservers can point to my particular IP (which is static) and I've opened that domain outside of my local network so I know it works.

My problem is that when I try and access the website I made on WordPress (nothing fancy, just the basic stuff) it only opens the XAMPP dashboard.

If I manually put in the link it shows up as an error:

> 'Oops!' error page.

I want the domain that I bought to open up my website.

How do I do that?

Comment: I did search for other questions on the stack exchange on how to do this and couldn't find anything I could understand to be useful, but I just found: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL and I think that that may have the answer. If anyone agrees let me know.

Comment: Where is your WordPress installation located in your `xampp/htdocs` folder? What URL did you enter when you got your *xampp* dashboard? Which one (URL) did you enter when you got the *'Oops!' error page.*?

Comment: My WordPress installation is on a folder within htdocs. That would be xampp/htdocs/816 (where 816 is the name of the website I made). The URL is that of the domain I bought (say example.com), like this: example.com/wordpress. I also put that in the WordPress settings area where you can edit the site address. Also I would like the URL I use for my website not to have 'wordpress' in it, if that were possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you've installed WordPress as described [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress), directly in a folders named `816` under your `xampp/htdocs/`, and this, without any alterations (modifying settings or any configurations to neither your xampp nor WordPress installation); having defined the *nameservers* of your domain name (here, `example.com`) to point to your IP, let's say: `192.182.230.1`,

The following apply (when your xampp is up and running with Apache and MySQL started):

- Visiting `example.com` in your browser should redirect you to `example.com/dashboard/`
- Visiting `example.com/816` in your browser should take you to your WordPress installation.

As such, if you've installed your WordPress by accessing `localhost/816` in your browser, `example.com/816` will redirect you to `http://localhost/816`, the actual location where your you've installed your WordPress site.

Should you have done so using your IP in place of `localhost`, I guess `example.com/816` should redirect you to `192.182.230.1/816`.

In order for `example.com/816` to remain unchanged and point directly to your WordPress installation, you can do so by accessing your WordPress administration panel, then, head over to your *Settings* -> *General*; there, modify your *WordPress Address (URL)* and your *Site Address (URL)* from their current (either `http://localhost/816` or `http://192.182.230.1/816`) states to `http://example.com/816` and do remember to click on the Save Changes button so as to effect your modifications.

Should you want to access your WordPress site directly on `example.com` instead of `example.com/816`, you will have to set up a virtual host in order to achieve that.

Setting up a virtual host requires you edit your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. You can locate it in your `xampp/apache/conf/extra/` directory.

You can make use of the snippet below to set up your virtual host by adding it to your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file.

Do remember to save it, then, restart Apache so as to enable the change you just made take effect.

```
# VirtualHost for example.com
# Here, it is assumed your xampp was installed directly
# at the root of the drive C of your computer, in a folder named xampp.
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\816"
    ServerAdmin example.com
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\816">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After setting up your virtual host as described above, you can now go to your WordPress Dashboard *Settings* -> *General*, then, define `example.com` as your *WordPress Address (URL)* and your *Site Address (URL)*; this will enable you to always access the content of your WordPress site directly on your domain name, `example.com`.